# Making PHP menu-submenu system with MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql, menu, mysqli, submenu

I am trying to make menu-submenu with php & MySQLi.
I have this table:
[image]

And I have this php code:

```
function my_menu($parent_id=0){
    $connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
            mysql_select_db("a_personality",$connection);
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent_id = {$parent_id}");

            if(mysql_num_rows($query)){
                echo "<ul>";
                while($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
                    echo "<li>";
                    echo $res['name'];
                    dispay_menu($res['cat_id']);
                    echo "</li>";
                }
                echo "</ul>";
            }
}
```

But I have to write it with MySQLi, and I did this:

```
function dispay_menu($mysqli_conn,$parent_id=0){

            $query = $mysqli_conn->prepare("SELECT cat_id,name,parent_id FROM categories WHERE parent_id = ?");
            $query->bind_param('i',$parent_id);
            $query->execute();
            $query->bind_result($cat_id_db,$name_db,$parent_id_db);


            if($query->num_rows){
                echo "<ul>";
                while($query->fetch()){
                    echo "<li>";
                    echo $name_db;
                    echo "<script>alert('".$parent_id_db."');</script>";
                    dispay_menu($mysqli_conn,$parent_id_db);
                    echo "</li>";
                }
                echo "</ul>";
            }
}
```

Function with mysqli I call like this: **dispay_menu($mysqli_conn);**
Problem is that my function with mysqli doesn't work, what is the problem?

Than you!

Comment: What do you mean it "doesn't work". Any errors? Any warnings?

Comment: The following variables are undefined in this function display_menu: $cat_id_db,$name_db,$parent_id_db. That is why, maybe your function isn't getting executed properly. You can either define these variables inside this function or pass them as parameters to this function.

Comment: if I remove if($query->num_rows) this I get error Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\...

Comment: @KanishkDudeja the variables are created by `mysqli_stmt::bind_result()`

Comment: If `$query` is not an object add `echo $mysqli_conn->error;` after the `$mysqli_conn->prepare();` call.

Comment: Now I have this error  Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
dispay_menu($mysqli_conn,$parent_id_db);
```

with

```
dispay_menu($mysqli_conn,$cat_id_db);
```

Currently you always call the submenu with parent id `0`.

Comment: Again doesn't work :( if I remove if($query->num_rows) this I get error 
And Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs....